# Camera roll constantly downloading after restoring iCloud

Tags: icloud, restore

I use iCloud transfer pictures from old phone to iPhone 5s, but camera roll is constantly downloading after restoring iCloud... How can I stop this?

Comment: When you say that you camera roll is constantly downloading, I do not understand... what do you mean exactly by that ? What is happening concretely ?

Comment: Are you looking for someone to answer "Go to settings and turn off the cloud photo stream?" or is there something else you don't get about how the software works?

Answer (score 1):

> One solution is deleting all photos from Photo Stream.

So your iPhone is downloading all the Photos located at Photo Stream. **Import this pictures once in your iPhone or Mac, and then delete Photo Stream.**